# Extrude building footprints using raster (DSM) values in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: dem, arcgis-pro, extrude

Is there a way to extrude a buildings footprint shapefile into 3D buildings using values from the area's DSM in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Given a DEM and DSM:

[image]

Use raster calculator to compute height:

[image]

Compute zonal statistics for your shapefile using height raster:

[image]

Join table to shapefile and extrude geometries using fields created with Zonal statistics process:

[image]